# Beautify exceptions from triggers in Lightning UI

Tags: apex, trigger, exception

I have a function that I fire on an after insert or update of my `Inventory__c` object

```
public class duplicateException extends Exception {}

public static void preventDuplication (List<Inventory__c> inventories) {
    List<String> NDCs = new List<String>();

    for(Inventory__c i : inventories) {
        NDCs.add(i.NDC__c);            
    }

    Set<String> inventoryNames = new Set<String>();

    for(Inventory__c i : [SELECT Drug_Name__c, FillingPharmacy__c FROM Inventory__c WHERE NDC__c IN :NDCs]) {
        String inventoryName = i.FillingPharmacy__c + ': ' + i.Drug_Name__c;

        if(inventoryNames.contains(inventoryName)) {
            auraError('The inventory for ' + i.Drug_Name__c + ' is already being tracked at ' + i.FillingPharmacy__c);
        } else {
            inventoryNames.add(inventoryName);
        }
    }
}
```

The functionality works, but there is a lot going on when the duplicate check exception fires. Is there any way to clean this up so users only see the message I'm setting, and not all the apex class/triger names/lines?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use exceptions to report errors in a trigger. Use [sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)#addError to report errors correctly. This is true for both Classic and Lightning, as well as for the API. Using addError will give you a consistent error report across all types of Salesforce interactions.

---

```
public static void preventDuplication (List<Inventory__c> inventories) {
  Map<Inventory__c, Inventory__c> keyMap = new Map<Inventory__c, Inventory__c>();
  Set<String> ndcs = new Set<String>(),
    drugNames = new Set<String>(),
    pharmacies = new Set<String>();
  for(Inventory__c record: inventories) {
    keyMap.put(new Inventory__c(NDC__c=record.NDC__c, Drug_Name__c=record.Drug_Name__c, FillingPharmacy__c=record.FillingPharmacy__c), record);
    ndcs.add(record.NDC__c);
    drugNames.add(record.Drug_Name__c);
    pharmacies.add(record.FillingPharmacy__c);
  }
  for(Inventory__c matchingRecord: [SELECT Drug_name__c, FillingPharmacy__c, NDC__c FROM Inventory__c WHERE NDC__c = :ndcs AND Drug_Name__c = :drugNames AND FillingPharmacy__c = :pharmacies]) {
    Inventory__c key = new Inventory__c(NDC__c=matchingRecord.NDC__c, FillingPharmacy__c=matchingRecord.FillingPharmacy__c, Drug_name__c=matchingRecord.Drug_name__c),
      sourceRecord = keyMap.get(key);
    if(key != null && key.Id != sourceRecord.Id) {
      sourceRecord.addError('The inventory for ' + matchingRecord.Drug_Name__c + ' is already being tracked at ' + matchingRecord.FillingPharmacy__c);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when I use the addError feature, it doesn't allow me to display an custom error message. I think it's because I'm using `addError()` on a record from the SOQL query, and not from the current record that trigger the exception.

Comment: it gives this error message: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors

Comment: @TylerZika You need to look up the appropriate record in the trigger. P.S. I also don't think your code is properly bulkified, which may be part of your problem.

Comment: @TylerZika I edited in an optimized version of your trigger that uses addError correctly and is bulkified for optimal performance.